# Confirm password field always prints "pw don't match" while registering

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

Please have a look at the following site:

http://openstrategynetwork.com/joinus

Username: **uzh**
Password: **osn**

Now please fill a password and confirm it (no need to register)

Although the repeated password is the same, it always prints:

```
Passwords don't match.
```

Why is that? However, after hitting the register button (still no need to register or fill out the other fields), the css shows a matching sign.

I’m using the `useraccounts` package: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts

Here's the code, especially my own templates: 
https://github.com/OpenStratNet/OSN/tree/master/client/templates/account-templates

Any help highly appreciated.

Edit (my config file):

```
// Options
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  // preSignUpHook: function (error, state) {
  //   console.log("love");
  // },
  // defaultLayout: 'emptyLayout',
  showForgotPasswordLink: true,
  overrideLoginErrors: true,
  enablePasswordChange: true,

  // sendVerificationEmail: true,
  // enforceEmailVerification: true,
  //confirmPassword: true,
  //continuousValidation: false,
  showLabels: false,
  //forbidClientAccountCreation: true,
  //formValidationFeedback: true,
  homeRoutePath: '/',
  redirectTimeout: 2000,
  //showAddRemoveServices: false,
  showPlaceholders: true,

  negativeValidation: true,
  positiveValidation: true,
  negativeFeedback: true,
  positiveFeedback: true,

  // Privacy Policy and Terms of Use
  //privacyUrl: 'privacy',
  //termsUrl: 'terms-of-use',
  texts: {
    sep: "OR REGISTER with your social account:",
    title: {
      signUp: "REGISTER by creating a new account:"
    },
    button: {
      signUp: "REGISTER"
    },
    socialSignUp: "",
    socialWith: ""
  }
});

var submitFunction = function(error, state){
  // ...
};


// remove fields and add them back in the right order
AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');
AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');

//all register fields
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
    {
      _id: 'firstName',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "First Name*",
      required: true,
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter your first name.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'lastName',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Last Name*",
      required: true,
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter your last name.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: "Email Address*",
      required: true,
      displayName: "email",
      re: /.+@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/,
      errStr: 'Invalid email',
    },
    {
      _id: 'institution',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Institution/Company*",
      required: true,
      // re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      minLength: 2,
      errStr: "Please enter the institution or company you work for.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'interests',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Interests regarding Open Strategy*",
      required: true,
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter the your interests in the institution/company.",
      template: 'interests'
    },
    {
      _id: 'position',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Position",
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter the your position in the institution/company.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'uploadProfile',
      type: 'text',
      template: 'uploadInput'
    },
    {
      _id: 'password',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: "Password*",
      required: true,
      minLength: 6,
      errStr: 'Password must be at least six characters long',
    },
    {
      _id: 'password_again',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: "Confirm Password*",
      required: true,
      minLength: 6,
      errStr: 'Password must be at least six characters long',
    }
]);
```

Adding the line `AccountsTemplates.removeField('password_again');` before adding the field again gives the following error:

> core.js:591Uncaught Error: A field called password_again does not
>   exist!AT.removeField @ core.js:591(anonymous function) @
>   at_config.js:61(anonymous function) @ at_config.js?2f3c438…:136

and right after that:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_id' of undefinedAT._init @
>   client.js:146(anonymous function) @ client.js:463runStartupCallbacks @
>   startup_client.js:30ready @ startup_client.js:32 debug.js:41 Exception
>   in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of
>   undefined
>       at Object.showError (http://localhost:3000/packages/useraccounts_core.js?e3a764dbf634d8bf2a393797c0a82e9fadef2e7a:1555:41)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/kadira_debug.js?49a4c0aadab9f87c37a2964e832426eebd091e3c:469:23
>       at withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:971:17)
>       at Store.onTracking (http://localhost:3000/packages/kadira_debug.js?49a4c0aadab9f87c37a2964e832426eebd091e3c:157:28)
>       at Object.dict.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/packages/kadira_debug.js?49a4c0aadab9f87c37a2964e832426eebd091e3c:468:39)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/peerlibrary_blaze-components.js?015e1eb30b191686996f3bedbd6f966c5b6ef6c1:373:21
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:1650:16
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/peerlibrary_blaze-components.js?015e1eb30b191686996f3bedbd6f966c5b6ef6c1:392:66
>       at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?9391df93ba5076c2cfc61ee68724eb79b65f00d9:3671:12)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/peerlibrary_blaze-components.js?015e1eb30b191686996f3bedbd6f966c5b6ef6c1:391:27

Comment: Could you please try to uncomment `confirmPassword: true` in your `OSN/lib/config/at_config.js`? Also, this error could be caused by not removing the filed `password_again` with `AccountsTemplates.removeField('password_again');`, before adding it again.

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart: ```confirmPassword``` didn't have any effect. ```AccountsTemplates.removeField('password_again');``` gives an error: "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry, and this error before: client.js:146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_id' of undefined. I add an image to the post.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found out that the `password_again` field is cloned from the `password` field, so there is no need to remove it manually.

Comment: Alright thx - good to know. A pity it wasn't ```confirmPassword: true```.